# JS validation numbers only?

Tags: javascript

I have 5 text boxes I will get prices how can I validate there is only numbers on those text boxes if there is a letter I want to give a alert when submit. 
How can I do that please help me Im new to these stuff

```
<input type="text" id="sellingPrice"><br>
<input type="text" id="basicPrice"><br>
<input type="text" id="latestBuyingPrice"><br>
<input type="text" id="ReorderQuantity"><br>
<input type="text" id="reorderLevel"><br>

<button id="save_P" type="button" class="save-button-text save-button displayShow" onclick="submitDetails()">
```

how can I use number validation in `submitDetails()` method

Comment: the easiest way would be to use type="number" instead of text, then user will be able to enter only numbers. More info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Comment: Specify text boxes as type=number

Comment: I want to give a alert when submit, as its not a number

Comment: You wouldn't want the Client to set your price. If you're just doing homework then, in IE10+ you can use `<input type='number' />`, but if you want backward compatibility you use a `RegExp`. Note that `<input type='text' />` will give you a String. If you need to do Math make sure you cast to a number like `var num = +stringHere;`. Keep in mind JavaScript has addition and subtraction issues with decimals. To resolve this issue, multiply by `Math.pow(10, 17)` to remove the decimals, then divide by the same to get the decimals back correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty common issue, but there are a couple ways to approach it:

1. Verify using Regular Expressions
2. Attempt to parse the number and check if `isNaN(parsedResult)` returns true

By far, I believe the most common approach is `var num = parseFloat(StringNumberFromTextbox), isValidNumber = (!isNaN(num) && isFinite(num));`

If you went the RegEx route, you could use: `var rNumPattern=/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/, isValidNumber = rNumPattern.test(StringNumberFromTextbox);`

You might also consider consider checking negative/positive signs and thousands separators using replacements of commas or periods (as appropriate for the locale/clientele).

Of course, if you are then submitting those on a form to some backend processor, you would be wise to check those numbers again on the server-side rather than blindly trusting that the client has provided valid numbers just because your JavaScript should done the checking. Lest you end up with a SQL vulnerability or the like.

Answer (score 0):

You can add type="number" attribute to input tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it using `isNaN(value)` inbuilt function of JavaScript.

Your function could be like this:

```
    function submitDetails() {

      var val = document.getElementById("sellingPrice").value;

      if (isNaN(val)) {
        // show alert here
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In submitDetails() use following code.

```
var sellingPrice=document.getElementById("sellingPrice").value;
//repeat above code for all field.
if(Number.isInteger(sellingPrice) == false){
 alert('wrong value entered');
}
//repeat above if code for all value.
```

This will do what you want.

Comment: if I want to accept something like 44.44 with two decimal points how can i do that

Comment: then use .isNaN in place of .isInteger